# ¿Como puedo aplicar un while aqui?

Tags: linux, bash, script, while

Estoy buscando conseguir poner un while que haga basicamente que: while $opt sea diferente de "salir" haga un echo que pongo "Elije", y tengo 2 problemas:

1. No se si es correcto el planteamiento que he hecho en el script
2. que cuando lo ejecuto me da un syntax error por el ultimo done que en teoria uno es para cerrar el case y el otro para cerrar el while.

Si tienen alguna sugerencia o saben como hacerlo estaría muy agradecido

```
while $opt != "salir"
                echo "Elije"
                
sleep 1

PS3="Elige tu opción: "

opciones=("detener" "iniciar" "ram" "cpu" "salir")

select opt in "${opciones[@]}"

do
    case $opt in 

        "detener") echo "Has elegido detener el contenedor $CONT " 
                (detener_maquina 2>&1) >> ./proceso.log; break
        ;;

        "iniciar") echo "Has elegido iniciar el contenedor $CONT " 
                (iniciar_maquina 2>&1) >> ./proceso.log ; break
        ;;

        "ram") echo "Has elegido gestionar la RAM del contenedor $CONT "
                (gestion_ram 2>&1) >> ./proceso.log; break
        ;;

        "cpu") echo "Has elegido gestionar la CPU del contenedor $CONT"
                (gestion_cpu 2>&1) >> ./proceso.log; break
        ;;
        "salir") break 2
        ;;
        *) echo "Opcion no válida."
    esac
done
done
```

Comment: estás haciendo preguntas muy seguidas sobre el mismo tema. Sugiero parar un momento a reflexionar sobre las respuestas recibidas antes de preguntar cosas nuevas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No da error por el `done` aunque en el error diga eso... Da error por el `while` del principio, esto hay que omitirlo de momento:

```
while $opt != "salir"
    echo "Elije"         
sleep 1
```

Cuando no se sabe qué valor devuelve la variable, una alternativa es ponerse de acuerdo entre el usuario y buscar la salida... Cuando pida la opción simplemente escribes `hola`, entonces, luego se busca entre todas las variables con `set` y `grep`.

```
"salir") break 2
;;
*) set | grep hola
;;
```

Código de *bash*:

```
#!/bin/sh

opt=2
PS3="Elige tu opción: "

opciones=("detener" "iniciar" "ram" "cpu" "salir")

select opt in ${opciones[@]}
do
    case opt in
        "detener") echo "Has elegido detener el contenedor $CONT " 
                (detener_maquina 2>&1) >> ./proceso.log; break
        ;;
        "iniciar") echo "Has elegido iniciar el contenedor $CONT " 
                (iniciar_maquina 2>&1) >> ./proceso.log ; break
        ;;
        "ram") echo "Has elegido gestionar la RAM del contenedor $CONT "
                (gestion_ram 2>&1) >> ./proceso.log; break
        ;;
        "cpu") echo "Has elegido gestionar la CPU del contenedor $CONT"
                (gestion_cpu 2>&1) >> ./proceso.log; break
        ;;
        "salir") break 2
        ;;
        *) set | grep hola
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Salida al escribir la palabra que pusimos en el `grep`:

```
REPLY=hola
```

Como se ve, encontramos la variable donde se guarda la respuesta del usuario... Ahora hay que escribirla en el código, primero cambiar la variable `case`:

```
select opt in ${opciones[@]}
do
    case $REPLY in
```

También en la línea de `salir`:

```
"salir") break 2
;;
*) echo "Opcion $REPLY no válida."
;;
```

Y por último hacer el `while`, englobando por fuera al `select`.

No olvidar poner el `;do` y los condicionales dobles para los strings, `[[ "$REPLY" != "salir" ]]`, los dos strings tienen que tener comillas dobles al principio y al final (`"$x"`).

También es mejor cambiar las palabras por números de opciones... En vez de lo siguiente:

```
"detener")
```

Poner solo números:

```
"1")
```

Código completo:

```
#!/bin/sh

PS3="Elige tu opción: "

opciones=("detener" "iniciar" "ram" "cpu" "salir")

while [[ "$REPLY" != "salir" ]]; do
    echo && echo "Reply: $REPLY"
    echo "Elije"
    select opt in ${opciones[@]}
    do
        case $REPLY in
            "1") echo "Has elegido detener el contenedor $CONT " 
                    (detener_maquina 2>&1) >> ./proceso.log; break
            ;;
            "2") echo "Has elegido iniciar el contenedor $CONT " 
                    (iniciar_maquina 2>&1) >> ./proceso.log ; break
            ;;
            "3") echo "Has elegido gestionar la RAM del contenedor $CONT "
                    (gestion_ram 2>&1) >> ./proceso.log; break
            ;;
            "4") echo "Has elegido gestionar la CPU del contenedor $CONT"
                    (gestion_cpu 2>&1) >> ./proceso.log; break
            ;;
            "5") break 2
            ;;
            *) echo "Opcion $REPLY no válida."
            ;;
        esac
    done
done
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, al final lo consegui solucionar por mi cuenta utilizando el siguiente codigo:

```
while [[ "opt" != "salir" &&  "opt" != "detener" && "opt" != "cpu" && "opt" != "ram" && "opt" != "iniciar"]]; do
```

Comment: @ShiroMB Eso está bien, pero son muchos condicionales, imagina si fueran 100 opciones, quedaría una línea muy larga y sería impráctico.